# Bake Mesh Analysis to Texture

Tags: mesh, scripting, texture-baking, 3d-printing

I'm guessing this would be pretty difficult, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the mesh analysis data to save as a texture. Specifically the thickness setting. The idea being to "bake" the mesh analysis display to save as an image.

I assume there's probably some way to do it with scripting, but that it's probably over my head at the moment.

Comment: You can either use the code in the [print3D addon](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/object_print3d_utils/mesh_helpers.py;f2bb66b68b4071c6554cae881010a783b3ebbdf0$144), with `from object_print3d_utils.mesh_helpers import bmesh_check_thick_object` or copy it's code and adapt it.

Answer (score 5):

There is not such feature for now, but ... specifically speaking about **Thickness** there is an OSL shader by [Róbert László Páli](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57755/2214), which use the same type of measurement - depth along the normal of the surface.

**Mesh Analysis - Thickness**
with values *Minimum* (Red) = 0, *Maximmum* (Blue) = 1

[image]

**OSL Shader**
To set the same distance use *Map Range* node *From Min* = 0, *From Max* = 1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks to Robin Betts for pointing me to Róbert's thread.