# How to turn on Mesh Analysis

Tags: mesh

for several day now, I solve the problem of crating a heatmap-texture based on its curvature. After quite long searching, I found Mesh Analysis (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html). However I discovered 2 problems:

1. How do I even turn this on in Blender 3.31? I can't find any button anywhere.
2. How can I then extract the texture that will be produced by the Mesh Analysis?

Thank you very much,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select your object.
2. Press <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> to go to *Edit Mode*, or switch it from the menu:

[image]

3. Press the  button near the [image] *Show Overlays* toggle to open the drop-down menu, in it you will find the *Mesh Analysis* option:

[image]

4. Enable the option and choose the mode and other settings below it:

[image]

### How to bake it to a texture?

See an existing thread: [Bake Mesh Analysis to Texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/73736/60486)