# Generation of a height map of a non-flat part

Tags: displacement, height-map

i want to generate a height map of a object that is curved.

[image]

In the end I want to to create a map of the THICKNESS of this part.

My idea is to create a height map that shows the height of the pink surface over the blue surface.

The blue surface of the part is pretty smooth, but not cylindrical.
The pink surface shows some heights and/or steps. --> I want to measure the height of these over the blue surface

Is this possible?
Can someone guide me to a tutorial how to do this?

I find many tutorials, but most of the usefull ones are of flat surfaces.

Thanks for the help

Comment: [Mesh Analysis](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html) might help.. or check out the Q&A [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/191299/35559)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, and sorry for the delay!
The link was very helpfull for me! I just found that ambien occlusion is not the right tool for my problem. In the end I have choosen a method of using 2 height-maps (from both sides of the part) and substracting them!   
I also take several image(pairs) to keep the distortion low.

Thanks anyhow