# Colorize bronchial tubes from wide to narrow

Tags: animation

I want to colorize these stylised bronchial tubes in an animation from the top (wider tube) to the bottom (narrow tubes). Do you have an idea how to achive this? Maybe with animation nodes? How would you do it?

Ideas are very welcome, thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: i don't think that's possible...but i am very curious for the answers here... ;) It should be possible with python so...

Comment: Have a look at the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/191299/35559), and the links out to @Pali's [OSL scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47172/35559). 'Thickness Shader' might be a good search-term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a *UV Unwrap > Project from View*, align the UV islands (subtrees) along the Y(V)-axis, and use a UVWrap modifier with 2 Empties or a driver in the Mapping Node to animate it:

[image: example animation]

If you want to make it perfect you need to rotate and align every branch top-down. I did it only for the main branches:

[image: UV map]

Set the extrapolation mode for the *Image Textexure* node to `Extended`:

[image: material setup]

Use the *UV Warp* modifier or the Y value of the *Mapping* node to animate the color.

Comment: Very smart solution! Thank you @Blunder!