# Best smoke settings to fill solid object

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am trying to fill the mesh shown below with thick smoke. To this end, I placed an emitter UV sphere inside the mesh and set the mesh to fluid effector. The smoke is now contained in the mesh. Now I would like it to fill the mesh but I cant seem to figure out how to best do this. I tried a wind forcefield to blow the smoke further into the mesh which works to some extent, but the smoke gets thin and invisible.
What would be a good way to fill the mesh starting from the emitter UV sphere? Any help is much appreciated!
Edit: I am aiming at an animation of the smoke filling the mesh from the UV sphere as a starting point.
Thank you.[image]
[image]

Comment: The best setting? Fake it with some Volumetric shader ... :) Smoke is really bad option in filling obtacles, even you increase density final shape would be cuby (if there wasnt major improvement in smoke sim).

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I am aiming at an animation though, so I am not sure how this would work. I have edited my question in this regard.

Comment: It was clear to me (you aim to anim) :) Do you have a reference how final anim should looks like? If not shader ... so probably some particle system or fluid sym with volumetric could be an experimental way here ...

Comment: The structure reminds me of this question [Colorize bronchial tubes from wide to narrow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/237198/107598). It uses UV mapping and a simple material shader -- For a smoke simulation, it might be easier to move the emitter(s) through the branches than to blow the smoke in there with the wind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example what I thought about *Volumetric Shader* ... here based on **Ambient Oclussion** with **Inside** option enabled (you can try also [these OSL scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57755/2214) if some will works better).

Probably can be used also as Density factor for Particle System ... ?

---

First I *Decimated* whole mesh to make lighter topology and deleted all inside mesh parts. You can do that easily by selecting one inner vertex and press L key (Linked), but first you would have to delete loops of a three veins ending open to inside.

[image]

For Volumetric you can animate Color Ramp to get impression of filling veins ...

[image]
Under 2.93 I used *Multiply* by **Math** node ...
for 3.2x has to be used **Vector Math** node instead.

[image]

Notes:

- works for 2.93 and 3.2 (some bug for 3.0 and 3.1)
- link to OSL script technique works, but for me only as internal text (not externally)

[image]
Version for 2.93

In combination with some *Noise* texture you can try more smokish leaning effect.

Comment: This will work just nicely! Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: Just a quick follow-up: this works nicely in Blender 2.93. However, for some reason I cant get it to work in Blender 3.0 or Blender 3.1. Which version did you use?

Comment: I see ... :) I used 2.8 at home on very old machine. At work I see 3.1 has some problem, but seems to be fixed for 3.2 ... you would have to use to Multiply (more logical) by using "Vector Math" node (not the "Math" node that worked in 2.93) https://imgur.com/3n5eMiU ... later I will fix the answer. Thanks for notification :)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!